# C# Reopening a form with CefSharp

Tags: c#, forms, cefsharp

There is a code:

```
        MainBot mainBot = new MainBot ();
        mainBot.IdBot = "hm";
        mainBot.Url = "https://www.home-style.shop/";
        mainBot.Proxy = "";
        mainBot.IdBtn = "";
        mainBot.TimeBtnClick = 1000;
        mainBot.TimeReturn = 5000;
        mainBot.Show ();
```

It opens the form as if with a browser (using the CefSharp library), then closes it after the time specified in TimeReturn -> `this.Close ();`
When you reopen the form through the button, it writes -> "CEF can only be initialized once per process. This is a limitation of the underlying CEF / Chromium framework. You can change many (not all) settings at runtime through RequestContext.SetPreference. See https: //github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception. If you are seeing this unexpectedly then you are likely calling Cef.Initialize after you ' ve created an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, it must be before the first instance is created. "

Incilization can be performed once. Therefore, I added ** FormClosing ** to the form and entered `Cef.Shutdown ();` The initialization error was fixed, but now, when reopening, the form does not open, and the form from which it was opened simply hangs and closes.
Please tell me what to do

Comment: As the exception says use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against the exception. Only call Cef.Initialize if Cef.IsInitialized is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CefSharp can be initialized in 2 ways:

- explicit: call *Cef.Initialize(settings)* with appropiate *cefSettings*
- implicit: when you open a new *chromiumWebBrowser* CEF will initialize with default settings

Your code is not clear about how you perform the initialization part though.

Personally I prefer to do it explitly with my choice of cefSettings. Wherever you do it

- Main method
- form constructor
- load/show event

just make sure you call initialize only once per application !
I usually do it in the main method before opening any form.

Same goes with *cef.shutdown*: once called CEF can not be reopened again !
I call it after *application.run* before the application closes

More information in the [General Usage Guide](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown)